# NOT NULL constraint failed: name_tabel.name_field. Django - models.py

Tags: django, model

I am trying to add my field as optional, unfortunately it always ends with an error (as in Title). My model has 'null = True, blank = True' added according to the answers on the forum. I have also tried to delete all migrations and do them again, but I still have the same message. How can I solve this problem (set the field as optional) Any help will be appreciated.

```
class OrderingMassage(models.Model):
    massage_product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: The old objects need a instance of this `massage_product` from its table so try using a default i.e.  `default = "something"`

Comment: Was your problem resolved?

Comment: how can I mark your answer as the one that solves the problem?

Comment: Click on the check in front of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old objects need a instance of this `massage_product` from its table so try using a `default`:

```
class OrderingMassage(models.Model):
    massage_product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="someDefaultData" , null=True, blank=True)
```